# Is the electromagnetic field a collection of wavefunctions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, wavefunction

I was reading about quantisation of the electromagnetic field.

In the Fourier transformed domain, the electromagnetic field (classical) is described by four variables ($p_1$, $q_1$, $p_2$, $q_2$) at each point  of $R^3$ space, 2 momentum variables and 2 position variables. I mean the Fourier transform of the vector potential variables in the Coloumb gauge. This transform gives new variables $p$ and $q$.

To quantise, we promote each of the pairs of $p$ and $q$ to operators with canonical conjugate relations. That means two pairs of position-momentum operators at each point of $R^3$. That means two wave-functions $\psi_1 (q)$ and $\psi_2 (q)$ at each point $(k_1,k_2,k_3)$

So the complete state of the field would be described by something like $\psi (k_1,k_2,k_3, \lambda, q)$. $\lambda=1,2$ and $-\infty < k_1,k_2, k_3, q <\infty$. Is this correct?

Also, the eigenstates of energy of the field would be the states such that all the wavefunctions $\psi _{k1,k_2,k_3,\lambda} (q)$ are the eigenstates of the corresponding Harmonic oscillator at the point $(k_1,k_2,k_3,\lambda)$. Is this correct?

Also, a state with 2 photons is a state in which the wave-functions at each point are the energy eigensate number #2 of the corresponding oscillator (Is this correct?). What happens if some wavefunctions are in the ground state of the corresponding oscillator, while others are in the #1 excited state? Is the photon description allowed for such a state?

Also, how does this $\psi (k_1,k_2,k_3, \lambda, q)$ "wave-function" transform as we switch from the Fourier domain $k$ back to the position domain $r$? What's the formula?

I know that multiple questions aren't allowed but these are yes/no questions, so forgive me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is *one* wavefunction that describes the state of *everything* in the Universe. Let's call this $\Psi$.

Now it's often the case that we want to study a particular subsystem, $S$. We can do this so long as the wavefunction *factorizes*, in the sense that we can write
\begin{equation}
\Psi = \Psi_S \Psi_{\rm everything\ else}
\end{equation}
where $\Psi_S$ is the wavefunction of the subsystem we want to study.

In your case, you want to take $S={\rm EM}$ to be the electromagnetic field. That's a fine thing to do. But note that now we have *one* wavefunction, call it $\Psi_{\rm EM}$, that describes *the entire* electromagnetic field.

In order to get a handle on $\Psi_{\rm EM}$, we want to expand it in basis of easy-to-understand eigenstates. A typical basis for describing a field is the [Fock space basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space). A single basis state will tell us how many photons are in each possible mode of the field.

As a simplified example, suppose we have a system with only three field modes and a single polarization, with angular frequencies $\omega$, $2 \omega$, and $3 \omega$. This is not realistic since the electromagnetic field has an infinite number of modes, but I suspect that you can clear up a lot of conceptual difficulties with this example, and once it is understood the jump from three modes to an infinite number of modes is not so hard. Then, here are some examples of basis states

- $|0\rangle | 0 \rangle | 0 \rangle$ -- the ground state, with zero photon excitations in each mode.
- $|1 \rangle | 0 \rangle | 0 \rangle$ -- 1 photon in the first mode with frequency $\omega$, zero photons in the other two modes.
- $| 0 \rangle | 1 \rangle | 0 \rangle$ -- 1 photon in the second mode with frequency $2 \omega$, zero photons in the other two modes.
- $| 0 \rangle | 0 \rangle | 1 \rangle$ -- 1 photon in the third mode with frequency $3 \omega$, zero photons in the other two modes.
- $| n_1 \rangle | n_2 \rangle | n_3 \rangle $ -- $n_1$ photons in the first mode with frequency $\omega$, $n_2$ photons in the second mode with frequency $2\omega$, $n_3$ photons in the third mode with frequency $3\omega$.

Then a generic state of this simplified model of the electromagnetic field can be written as
\begin{equation}
|\Psi_{\rm EM\ simplified}\rangle = \sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \sum_{n_3=0}^\infty c_{n_1, n_2, n_3} |n_1\rangle |n_2 \rangle | n_3 \rangle 
\end{equation}
where $c_{n_1, n_2, n_3}$ are a set of complex coefficients. This is the "wavefunction" (aka state) of the simplified electromagnetic field. As promised, we have a *single* state that describes the entire system.

To generalize this to the full electromagnetic field, we allow for an infinite number of modes, and we will have an expression like
\begin{equation}
|\Psi_{\rm EM} \rangle = \sum_{n_1=0}^\infty \sum_{n_2=0}^\infty \cdots \sum_{n_k=0}^\infty \cdots c_{n_1, n_2, \cdots n_k \cdots} |n_1\rangle |n_2 \rangle \cdots | n_k \rangle \cdots 
\end{equation}
Each mode is defined by a wavevector and a polarization. Again, we have a single state vector $|\Psi_{\rm EM}\rangle$ describing the entire electromagnetic field.

Comment: Would you say the $\psi (k_1,k_2,k_3, \lambda ,q)$ in my post is that one wave function? To clarify, by multiple wavefunction, I only meant "multiple" in the sense that, say, a particle with spin has two wavefunctions. I get that these multiple wavefunctions together form a single wavefunction of multiple components.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was trying to confirm. I understand that there's a single wavefunction in the end. You also confirmed that different modes are allowed to have different number of photons. Now I just need the formula to convert these wavefunctions from the $k$ domain to the $r$ domain. Do you have a link to that?

Comment: @RyderRude Sorry I deleted my comment, I need to reread what you wrote. I think what are describing is actually just the *single particle* part of the space. In other words, what you wrote as $\psi(k_1, k_2, k_3, \lambda, q)$ is actually analagous to the $c_{n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k, \cdots}$ when only one of $n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_k, \cdots$ is nonzero, and the non-zero $n$ is equal to one.

Comment: In general there is no position basis in quantum field theory, But, you can get away with assuming there is if you ignore interactions and transitions between states. What your text is probably assuming is that in a state with single excitation in a mode with wavenumber $\vec{k}$ and polarization $s$, that the position representation of the state is (up to normalization) $\vec{e}_s e^{i (\vec{k} \cdot x - \omega t)}$, where $\vec{e}_s$ is the polarization vector for the polarization $s$ and $\omega = |\vec{k}|/c$.

Comment: In other words, let $|\psi_{\vec{k}, s}\rangle = |0 \rangle \cdots |1\rangle | 0 \rangle \cdots$, where the state with a "1" has wavenumber $\vec{k}$ and polarization $s$. Then up to normalization $\langle x | \psi_{{\vec k}, s} \rangle = \vec{e}_s e^{i(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x} - \omega t)}$. Section 2.8.1 of David Tong's QFT notes has some words about the relation between the single particle space of QFT and ordinary quantum mechanics: https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html

Comment: I guess I'll have to read more on this... Thanks. I thought my wavefunction was generally describing any arbitrary number of photons at each possible $(\vec{k}, \lambda)$. The book I was reading mentioned that Gauss's law forces a polarisation and makes $\lambda =1,2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134737/discussion-between-andrew-and-ryder-rude).